# How to create attached view using UICollectionView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

After every 2 rows of collection view there is a separator that will be used to show banner ads. Please suggest a way to create this screen

Comment: Look for `SupplementaryViewsOfKind` stuff in the doc of `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the section header view.
Simply use the datasource method to provider as section header view an ad view.

You can follow this [link to a good tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the “viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:” method.

Check this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/) for more info.